# SQL Injection on a local server

Tags: php, sql, sql-injection

I have a project for a course where I connect to a local server `localhost:8080/website.php` and execute SQL Injection. The server has an Account ID Number and Password field. When submitted the ID and Password values are input into the SQL statement: `SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE id = (ID value) AND password = '(password value)'` How would I exploit this and perform SQL Injection?

I have tried a few thing listed below.

`' or 1=1 --` became `SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE id = 12345 AND password = '' or 1=1 --'` opens an account, its always the same account. How do I access a different account?

`'; INSERT INTO accounts(id,password) values('12345','abc');--` became `SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE id = 12345 AND password = ''; INSERT INTO accounts(id,password) values('12345','abc');--'` This gives a sql error

How do I log into any account without knowing an id, the `' or 1=1 --` logs into the same account no matter what I put for the ID. Also how do I create my own account in the database?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: 1) Is `magic_quotes` enabled on your server? It shouldn't be, and it would thwart your attempts. 2) I don't think any MySQL drivers for PHP (`mysql_*`, `mysqli_*`, PDO) support multiple queries in a single statement, so things like `command1; command2 ...` won't work. 3) Try adding a trailing space after `--`, so that you have `-- `. Alternatively, try `#` as your comment delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

You can send a value to invalidate the where and make always true the result. This will give you access to the system without knowing the password.

'or 1=1 --

Mike after I run your statement in sql I got this.

[image]

Comment: the key here is that you are making sql think that you have closed the single quote, the 1=1 ensures that the query will always return data. it also varies depending on what kind of SQL backend it is.

[sql injection cheat sheet](http://ckers.org/sqlinjection/)

Comment: Ok this works but it always accesses the same account no matter what I put in the account ID field. How do I access other accounts? And how do I add my own account to the database?

Comment: The user is the one used in the form. Try the insert with ' or 1=1; insert statement; --